# Bad Method CallException Method sortResourcesBy does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-nova

when i am reordering laravel nova nav-menu , this error comes,can anyone solve

```
Nova::sortResourcesBy(function ($resource) {
   return $resource::$priority ?? 9999;
});
```

Comment: Where have u added this code ?

Comment: in laravel nova, when added laravel resource manually in novaservice provider

Comment: i am using laravel nova 2.6

Comment: Probably `sortResourcesBy` added after version 2.6. Trying updating Nova version & try

Comment: yes, sortResourcesBy added in 3.*

Comment: and i'm working on 2.6